# auto-global search in salesforce service console

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I'm attempting to execute a global search via javascript from a console component, but it's only searching on one object when it is opened as a tab in the service console.

.../_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&sen=006&sen=00Q&sen=001&sen=003&str=somesearchstring

The url parameters specify the search type and the 'sen' params set which object tables the search will execute on (this one is opportunity, lead, account and contact).

It works fine outside of the console but when it is opened as a tab in the console it only searches on the last object listed in the url parameters - which is lead in this example. Here's the code:

```
//searchterm var is set elsewhere

function searchTab() {
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSearchTab);
}
    var openSearchTab = function openSearchTab(result) {     
        var tabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(tabId, '/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&sen=005&sen=006&sen=001&sen=003&sen=00Q&str='+searchTerm, true,searchTerm,openSuccess );
    };
var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
//Report whether opening the new tab was successful
    console.log(result.success);  
};
```

I've tried encoding the url, but that just broke the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by removing the object types out of the search and searching all.  Its not ideal but it works.

```
    function openPrimaryTabGlobalSearch() {
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined, 
           'https://cs11.my.salesforce.com/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?str=5551234567&initialViewMode=summary&searchAll=true',
           true, 'global');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following urlvars:

```
initialViewMode=summary&searchAll=true
```

Best of luck!